# Sending JSON File to Browser

Tags: php, json, database

My server has a MariaDB database running with data about music. I have a Table "Track" and a Table "Album", and I want a JSON file that has something like this:

```
"Album": [
{
  "Album_Name": "content"
  "Cover": "link to cover photo"
  "Year": "Year of release"
  "Tracklist":[
      "Track 1": "Track name"
      "Duration 1": "duration"
      "Track 2": "Track name"
      "Duration 2": "duration" 
  ]
}
]
```

Now I have the album table with the trackname, duration and trackid in one:

```
{
 "TrackID": "182",
 "AlbumID": "14",
 "TrackName": "Love Me Do",
 "Duration": "142",
 "ArtistID": "2",
 "GenreID": "3",
 "Album_Name": "1962-1966",
 "Cover": "https://img.discogs.com/Mu7NoQJHOHJhQF1O81Rw5huvs-Q=/fit-in/300x300/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(40)/discogs-images/R-936664-1357282605-3395.jpeg.jpg",
 "Year": "1973"
}
```

Here is the current code:

```
<?php

$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USERNAME = 'root';
$DB_PASSWORD = 'Luka123456$';
$DB_DATABASE = 'Manofy';

// open connection to mysql
$connection = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_DATABASE) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");

// DB query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Track INNER JOIN Album ON Track.AlbumID = Album.AlbumID ORDER BY Album.Album_Name";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

// close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);

// create array
$json = [];
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     $json[] = $row;
}

// send JSON to browser
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please show error that you get

Comment: I don't get an error but I get the second Json file and I want the first

Answer (score 0):

You have to group your track by Album by looping results.

First you need to get all Albums, then after get all Albums, you loop thought them and combine results of Tracks into Album

```
// query to get all Albums
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Album  ORDER BY Album.Album_Name";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " .mysqli_error($connection));

// create array of Albums
$albums_list= array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $albums_list[] = $row;
}
// loop your Albums list and group to Tracks List
$json_output = array("Album" => array());
if (count($albums_list))
    foreach ($albums_list as $key => $album) {

        $json_output['Album'][] = $album;
        $c_len = count($json_output['Album']);

        $track = array();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Track INNER JOIN Album WHERE Track.AlbumID = ".$album['AlbumID']." ORDER BY Track.TrackName";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " .mysqli_error($connection));
        while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $track[] = $row;
        }

        $json_output['Album'][$c_len-1]["Tracklist"] = $track;
    }
}
// send JSON to browser
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json_output);
```

I have not tested the code above yet but it should works.